# How to open duplicated question without being redirected?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, redirection

I'm looking for some special parameter (like ?redirect=no, or something), which will prevent the redirection for the question from non-authenticated users.

Currently the questions are opened correctly when I'm authenticated (or for high-rep users), but when I'm sending this question somewhere else (like opening them in Privacy mode), it got redirected.

Is it possible to prevent that from happening by adding some special parameter? Or is there any workaround (like Wikipedia does that)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `?noredirect=1` to the end of the question URL.

#### Example

Regular link: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748931/how-to-access-internal-static-strings-from-designer-cs-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748931/how-to-access-internal-static-strings-from-designer-cs-file)

Link with `?noredirect=1`: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748931/how-to-access-internal-static-strings-from-designer-cs-file?noredirect=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748931/how-to-access-internal-static-strings-from-designer-cs-file?noredirect=1)

Comment: Good one! Note the example is not valid anymore, since it is not a duplicate now